# What happens to permissions when a file goes to the recycle bin?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, explorer, ntfs, hardlink

I have a problem related to file management done by a service application. My problem is that users are able to move files to the recycle bin for which I've created a hardlink, and once they do this, I loose the ability to list the hardlinks available.

This appears to only happen when the removed hardlink file sits inside the `$RECYCLER` folder but not on a folder with similar permissions on the same disk.

To replicate my problem assume one has a user account named `Service` with a suitable password.

On the current user account:

```
md C:\tmp
echo CONTENTS>C:\tmp\1
fsutil hardlink create C:\tmp\2 C:\tmp\1
```

That would have created a file named `C:\tmp\1` and a hardlink to it named `C:\tmp\2`.

Now if you `runas` another terminal with user `Service` you can:

```
fsutil hardlink list C:\tmp\1
\tmp\1
\tmp\2
```

That works fine.

Now if you (as the original user) move the `2` file to the recycle bin, you cannot access the files as `Service`.

```
type C:\tmp\1
Access is denied.
fsutil hardlink list C:\tmp\1
Error:  Access is denied.
```

That's because Explorer will have changed the DACL on the file to a restrictive one where only the current user, `SYSTEM` and an Administrator have access to the file.

If you do a `icacls C:\tmp\1 /reset` as the original user, now you can access the contents of the file as `Service`:

```
type C:\tmp\1
CONTENTS
```

But if you try to list the hardlinks, it will show you the first link and an access denied error:

```
fsutil hardlink list C:\tmp\1
\tmp\1
Error:  Access is denied.
```

If you list the hardlinks on the file as the original user, you get to know the recycle bin path of the original file:

```
fsutil hardlink list C:\tmp\1
\tmp\1
\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-111111111-2222222222-3333333333-1002\$R1GX1HN
```

And if you move that file to another (as the original user) folder:

```
md C:\tmp2
move \$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-111111111-2222222222-3333333333-1002\$R1GX1HN C:\tmp2
```

Now as `Service` you can list all the hardlinks:

```
fsutil hardlink list C:\tmp\1
\tmp\1
\tmp2\$R1GX1HN
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Does this have anything to do with Mandatory Integrity Control?

Comment: The service has no access to the user's recycle bin folder. It should have SeChangeNotifyPrivilege to bypass traverse checking, so it should be able to access the file itself at a low level (e.g. via `CreateFileW` or C `_wopen`), but at a higher level a lot of programs need access to the parent directory, e.g. to be able to stat the file via `FindFirstFileW`.

Comment: So `FindFirstFileW` requires permission to access the parent folder?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `FindFirstFileNameW` which along with `FindNextFileNameW` are the functions used to get hardlinks associated with a file. You think that still requires reading of the parent directory?

Comment: That can be, but I'm having the problem using the Win32 API...the example was done with the command line so it is easily reproducible.

Comment: `FindFirstFileNameW` opens the file and calls `NtQueryInformationFile` : `FileHardLinkInformation`. This returns [`FILE_LINK_ENTRY_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_link_entry_information) records. Notice that it's not the full path of the link on the volume. It's the link base filename and the ID of the parent directory. So `FindFirstFileNameW` or `FindNextFileNameW` has to open the parent directory by ID in order to query its path. In the case of the link in the recycle bin, it fails with access denied.

Comment: Excellent. That explains it. Do you think I can fix that problem by adding the `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` to the service user? Also, can you put that as an answer so I can give you due credit?

Comment: The access it needs on the link's parent directory is `SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: SeChangeNotifyPrivilege allows *traversing* a directory regardless of your access. It doesn't allow actually getting access to a directory that you're not granted. That you can get via SeBackupPrivilege -- but only if the `NtCreateFile` or `NtOpenFile` call actually requests backup semantics. Let me check this case.

Comment: Nope. The `NtCreateFile` call uses the options `FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID | FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`. It doesn't include the option `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT`, so enabling SeBackupPrivilege won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments by [@Eryk Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryk-sun), the problem is related to the way hardlinks are reported by Win32 API.

It appears that `fsutil` uses `FindFirstFileName` and `FindNextFileName` functions, both of which use `NtQueryInformationFile` which in turn returns a structure with entries of type [`FILE_LINK_ENTRY_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_link_entry_information) which have the hardlink name and the parent folder `NTFS ID`.

The problem manifests itself when the caller does not have permission to open the containing folder to get its name (probably using [`OpenFileById`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilebyid) and [`GetFinalPathByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea)).